# C++ Recursive Template Specialization - Missing Proper Parameter Pack Expansion

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, template-specialization, parameter-expansion

### Background & Goal

I wanted to create some sort of data utility, that stores an `std::stringstream`, as well as the format, the content is currently in. This shall give you type safety and IntelliSense as to that content representation your data currently has. Basically, it creates or removes a template parameter for every operation (compression, encoding, parsing, etc.):

```cpp
// content representations/states
enum class ContentTypes
{
    binary = 1,
    text = 2,
    json = 3,
    zlib = 4
};

template <ContentTypes... PreviousTypes>
class X
{
public:
    X<ContentTypes::zlib, PreviousTypes...> zlib()
    {
        return X<ContentTypes::zlib, PreviousTypes...>();
    }
};

template <ContentTypes... PreviousTypes>
class X<ContentTypes::zlib, PreviousTypes...> : public X<(ContentTypes::zlib, PreviousTypes)...>
{
public:
    X<PreviousTypes...> decompress()
    {
        return X<PreviousTypes...>();
    }
};

#include <string>
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    /// deterministic and compile-time safety as to what content type the data has
    X<ContentTypes::binary> foo;                    // some binary data (X<ContentTypes::binary>)
    auto compressed = foo.zlib();                   // X<ContentTypes::zlib, ContentTypes::binary>
    auto compressed2 = compressed.zlib();           // X<ContentTypes::zlib, ContentTypes::zlib, ContentTypes::binary>
    auto decompressed = compressed2.decompress();   // X<ContentTypes::zlib, ContentTypes::binary>
    auto decompressed2 = decompressed.decompress(); // X<ContentTypes::binary>
    return 0;
}
```

### Problem

as you may have noticed, there is a mistake in the template specialization:

```cpp
class X<ContentTypes::zlib, PreviousTypes...> : public X<(ContentTypes::zlib, PreviousTypes)...>
```

which results in wrong content types. If you try to compile the above code, you will get an error that the variable `decompressed` (which is actually of type `X<ContentTypes::binary>`, instead of `X<ContentTypes::zlib, ContentTypes::binary>`) has no attribute `decompress`. That is correct, since `X<ContentTypes::binary>` has no function called `decompress`. I don't know how to "inherit" the methods of the upper template instantiation to the specialization in the lower one without ending up with a recursive template.

##### The resulting GCC error:

```
.../src/main.cpp:52:39: error: 'class X<ContentTypes::binary>' has no member named 'decompress'
   52 |     auto decompressed2 = decompressed.decompress(); // X<ContentTypes::binary>
      |                                       ^~~~~~~~~~
```

### Attempts so far

- I've searched some literature on C++ template specialization and parameter pack expansion, but to no success
- ChatGPT was great for discovering new ways to break my code and offered the `(ContentTypes::zlib, PreviousTypes)...` expansion, which I think isn't correct at all because it just performs comma operator...

If you need more information, just ask in a comment.
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: please include the verbatim error message in the question. I get different error https://godbolt.org/z/qz3zT41br

Comment: "the variable decompressed has type X<ContentTypes::binary>, instead of X<ContentTypes::zlib, ContentTypes::binary>" thats not what the error says. Its the reason why the error happens, but the actual error is something else. Details matter

Comment: I believe it's because type of `compressed2` isn't what you expected. It's `X<ContentTypes::zlib, ContentTypes::binary>` instead of `X<ContentTypes::zlib, ContentTypes::zlib, ContentTypes::binary>`. Check this [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Y8c1ecsM9)

Comment: @LouisGo Correct! This is the underlying problem. I don't know how to do the specialization where I define `decompress` and also inherit `compress` from the upper template, without messing up the template parameters :D

Comment: You simply cannot pull a function from a primary template to a specialization by inheritance.

Comment: If you go further, the removal seems wrong: `X<json, zlib, text>::decompress` would return `X<text>`... Not sure if you want to be able to call compressed twice neither.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the helpful comments!
I received a hint that brought me to a working solution:

#### Full code

```cpp
enum class ContentTypes
{
    binary = 1,
    text = 2,
    json = 3,
    zlib = 4
};


template <ContentTypes... PreviousTypes>
class X;

template <ContentTypes... PreviousTypes>
class XBase
{
public:
    X<ContentTypes::zlib, PreviousTypes...> zlib()
    {
        return X<ContentTypes::zlib, PreviousTypes...>();
    }
};

template <ContentTypes... PreviousTypes>
class X : public XBase<PreviousTypes...>
{
};

template <ContentTypes... PreviousTypes>
class X<ContentTypes::zlib, PreviousTypes...> : public XBase<ContentTypes::zlib, PreviousTypes...>
{
public:
    X<PreviousTypes...> decompress()
    {
        return X<PreviousTypes...>();
    }
};


#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    /// deterministic and compile-time safety as to what content type the data has
    X<ContentTypes::binary> foo;                    // some binary data (X<ContentTypes::binary>)
    auto compressed = foo.zlib();                   // X<ContentTypes::zlib, ContentTypes::binary>
    auto compressed2 = compressed.zlib();           // X<ContentTypes::zlib, ContentTypes::zlib, ContentTypes::binary>
    auto decompressed = compressed2.decompress();   // X<ContentTypes::zlib, ContentTypes::binary>
    auto decompressed2 = decompressed.decompress(); // X<ContentTypes::binary>
    return 0;
}
```

#### Explaination

The inheritance done in a proper way would create a recursive template, which aborts compilation, since the name of the derived and parent class are identical (`X`). Just by renaming the parent class to `Xbase` and inheriting from that, this problem is solved. Now you just need to create a new base template class `X` that also inherits from `XBase` to make things complete.